# Where do I connect my mongodb Atlas to my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am building a React app with node.js with mongodb Atlas database. I have created the mongodb Atlas cluster and need to connect it to the React app. The mongodb documentation  says to use this code

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var uri = "mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test";
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
   // perform actions on the collection object
   client.close();
});
```

But - I'm not exactly sure where in my React app it should go. I am using react-router-dom and most places I put it breaks the app. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This code is designed to be used on **server side** of your app. As You've mentioned You have `Node.js` server, so put it there and use database connection to serve your data to the `React` client app.
For example, You can send some data to client when your server receives **HTTP request** with some endpoint.
[Here](https://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html) is nice tutorial for that :)